# Issue in map loading, its getting loaded in disarranged tiles out of which some tiles are blank

Tags: react-leaflet

Node version: 6.10.2
react-leaflet version: 1.1.6
leaflet version: 1.0.3
[image]

Issue is map is not getting load, irrespective of number of times you refresh your screen. Repository on which I am trying this is a basic boiler plate repository with nothing fancy. I have created the boiler plate using create-react-app.

Comment: Can you post the code that made the app?  Also, please post the css.

Comment: Got the solution....I haven't included leaflet.css in my existing css file. Now its working fine.

Comment: @NeerajYadav any example can show?